# MySQL nested query

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables, one containing products, one purchases.  I'm trying to find the average of the last 3 purchase prices for each product. So in the example below, for the product 'beans' I would want to return the average of the last 3 purchase prices before the product time 1230854663, i.e. average of customer C,D,E (239)

**Products**

```
+-------+------------+
| Name  | time       |
+-------+------------+
| beans | 1230854764 |
+-------+------------+
```

**Purchases**

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| Customer | time       | price |
+----------+------------+-------+
| B        | 1230854661 |   207 |
| C        | 1230854662 |   444 |
| D        | 1230854663 |    66 |
| E        | 1230854764 |    88 |
| A        | 1230854660 |   155 |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

I've come up with a nested select query which nearly gets me there i.e. it works if I hard code the time:

`SELECT products.name,(SELECT avg(temp.price) FROM (select purchases.price from purchases WHERE purchases.time < 1230854764 order by purchases.time desc limit 3) temp) as av_price
from products products`

But if the query references product.time rather than a hard coded time such as below I get an error that column products.time does not exist.

`SELECT products.name,(SELECT avg(temp.price) FROM (select purchases.price from purchases WHERE purchases.time < products.time order by purchases.time desc limit 3) temp) as av_price from products products`

I'm not sure if I'm making a simple mistake with nested queries or I'm going about this in totally the wrong way and should be using joins or some other construct, either way I'm stuck.  Any help would be greatfully received.

Comment: Do you mean "average of the last 3 purchase prices before the product time 1230854764"? No, that doesn't make sense either. I'm confused by your time values, are they correct?

Comment: Your table structures aren't normalized. "Purchases" doesn't have any product data.

Comment: Is there only one record in `Products`?  If they are multiple records, how do they relate to `Purchases`?

Comment: Please provide structures of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem in your query is you haven't mentioned **products** table in your inner query.

```
SELECT products.name,(SELECT avg(temp.price) 
FROM (select purchases.price from purchases,products 
WHERE purchases.time < products.time order by purchases.time desc limit 3) temp) as
av_price from products products
```